# how to correctly return std::list from dll

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

the project has this structure:
1. Dll - with core logic and class hierarchy
2. exe - console app which processes commandline and starts the algorithms
3. Dll - tests, like a unit test kit - hardcoded filling up the collection of the ojects from first Dll and passes the collection to exe console to process

so Dll point 3 should return the collection (e.g. std::list), the collection contains polymorphic objects, then should store the pointer,
I'd prefer to use std::unique_ptr instead of raw pointers

I see that unique_ptr supports move semantic only and I'm filling up the list using emplace_back member.
however there is a problem to return std::list> collection from Dll related with MSVC class exporting technique

if I understand this right :
shared between dll and exe projects header should contain something like this where EXP_DLL should be defined for Dll and undefined for exe

```
 #ifdef EXP_STL
 #    define DECLSPECIFIER __declspec(dllexport)
 #    define EXPIMP_TEMPLATE
 #else
 #    define DECLSPECIFIER __declspec(dllimport)
 #    define EXPIMP_TEMPLATE extern
 #endif

 EXPIMP_TEMPLATE template class DECLSPECIFIER std::list<std::unique_ptr<MyBassClass>>;

 std::list<std::unique_ptr<MyBassClass>> DECLSPECIFIER make_test_array();
```

this definition:

```
 EXPIMP_TEMPLATE template class DECLSPECIFIER std::list<std::unique_ptr<MyBassClass>>;
```

raises the error

> C2280:std::unique_ptr>::unique_ptr(const
>   std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)' : attempting to
>   reference a deleted function

I see the attempt to call copying ctor of unique_ptr (of course, deleted)

could you clarify these questions for me:

1. how this export declaration of instantiated template can call copying ctor here?
2. could you suggest the solution how to avoid this ?

Comment: Passing ownership of dynamically allocated memory out of a DLL can be a bit dangerous. As I recall Microsoft's compiler does a bit of magic to let it work, but more generally I think it would be necessary with a custom allocator.

Comment: Could you explain the reason of having your logic in DLL and not, say, in static library ?

Comment: no reasonable , just a user's requirement. I have to fill test structure up in separated Dll. P.S. that is a not production project of course , just a sample

Comment: You should not export C++ API from DLL. It can lead to many problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following conditons are met:

1. All projects in the solution link the same run-time DLL (/MD option)
2. Class MyBaseClass is attributed with DECLSPECIFIER.
3. Class MyBaseClass is completely defined before make_test_array declaration.

you must not export template specialization at all. Just remove the line `EXPIMP_TEMPLATE template class ...`. 
std::list and std::unique_ptr code will be inlined. 
You will get warning C4251, ignore it.

When you try to export `std::list` specialization, **all** `std::list<T>` methods are instantiated. Some of them (e.g. assignment operator) require T to be copyable. That's why specialization with unique_ptr can't be compiled.

Comment: points 1-3 do already exist. but if I remove export declaration of the list with unique_ptrs, the caller code in exe:     std::list<std::unique_ptr<MyBaseClass>> objects = make_test_array(); produces the error : unresolved external std::list<unique_ptr<MyBaseClass>>..... Of course, MyBaseClass is defined in that context, simple replacing with std::list<MyBasClass*> makes this workable but that is not what I want , you see

Comment: I was wrong - both variants with and without unique_ptr wrapper raise the error with unresolved external in exe

Comment: 1) Could you please specify the exact error text. 2) Are other exported function linked normally in exe?

Comment: 2) no - there is no other functions to export, this sample is my first experience, I didn't export stl objects earlier 1) (currently I removed unique_ptr from the list object and use raw pointers) main.obj:-1: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::list<class MyBaseClass *,class std::allocator<class MyBaseClass*> > __cdecl make_test_array(void)" (?make_test_array@@YA?AV?$list@PEAVMyBaseClass@@V?$allocator@PEAVMyBaseClass@@@std@@@std@@XZ) referenced in function main;

Comment: this code used: in exe: template class DECLSPECIFIER std::list<MyBasClass*>;

int main()
{
    std::list<MyBaseClass*> objects = make_test_array();                                                 and this in shared header: EXPIMP_TEMPLATE template class DECLSPECIFIER std::list<MyBaseClass*>;

std::list<MyBaseClass*> DECLSPECIFIER make_test_array();

Comment: I believe, there is a general problem with import/export, not related to std::list.

Comment: Thanks a lot! you were right, that was a general problem with dll exporting. I found the issue and for now, your inital solution works for the list of unique_ptrs. I don't technically understand the root of issue, that was a namespace. The declaration in header was : namespace MyProjectNS { std::list<std::unique_ptr<MyBaseClass>> DECLSPECIFIER make_test_array(); } like all others in the project. removing namespace solved the problem